# Which template file woocommerce is calling for product shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this shortcode `[products limit="4"]` to show the products on a different page called **Theme**.

Now I want to change the layout style of this **Theme** page by overriding woocommerce template file.

1) Which template file woocommerce is calling for this shortcode?

2) Can you give me a full reference where I can find which template file is responsive for which shortcode?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every shortcode related to product listing is calling template named `content-product.php` via follows -

`// Render product template.
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );`

You can find it [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/7222f982e23e95c69edb4c4d2d5dbbdd0f092d37/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-products.php#L653)

Comment: then which .php file I should check for this shortcode?  `[woocommerce_my_account]`

Comment: Check this function `self::my_account( $atts );`, its basically calling template named `myaccount/my-account.php`. For more info see [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/7222f982e23e95c69edb4c4d2d5dbbdd0f092d37/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php#L72)
And please if above answer is useful, mark and upvote it accepted for others help.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am looking for exact .php file name so that I can override my style into a new .php file.

Comment: Look WooCommerce my account page is a collection of endpoints and it's templates pages. Please confirm which section are you wanted.

Comment: I found the page I am looking for that is content-product.php file. But you know there are lots of shortcodes available in WC. So which WC is calling which .php file? If you can then share with me.

Comment: Look bro! As I already mentioned for every shortcodes (featured_products, top_rated_products, recent_products etc. ) related to product listing is called same template named `content-product.php`. And if you see WooCommerce plugin structure codes carefully, you will find that it's mostly  re-use templates whenever it's come product listing to inherit hooks / filters functionalities properly.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for you Help.